# How a function in window A got triggered when window B is close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please give me an example how a function X got triggered in window A when window B is closed.  For example, window A is launched first, and a button in window A is pressed, then window B is open and does something...then close window B.  As soon as window B is closed, the focus shifts to window A.  At this time, I would like a function X in window A is executed.  Plesae let me know how to do this in Javascript.

Comment: After a 3 second "Google": http://javascript.about.com/library/bltarget.htm - then you can use jQuery to sort out the focuses etc...

Comment: I have tried, but could not find the answer. Could you please let me know the link? Thank you.

Comment: erm...It's in that comment I posted...

Answer (score 0):

Register an event listener for the type `focus` on the `window` object:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    console.log("I'm focused again!");
    // Rest of your code
});
```

For IE<9, use `attachEvent` or, if you don't want any problem, define the `window.onfocus` property.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("focus", function() {     
      console.log("I'm focused again!"); 
      //exec_get_focus();
});

</script>

Comment: Oop, yes I got the message "I'm focused again!" by using your code, but when I activated my added function "exec_get_focus()" then I received error message" "Uncaught ReferenceError: exec_get_focus is not defined".  Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: That's because the function `exec_get_focus` isn't in the scope and the Javascript engine can't resolve it. You should provide some code. Do it editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Html5 has the [Page Visibility API](http://www.igvita.com/2011/06/25/html5-visibility-api-page-pre-rendering/)
to allow managing windows/tabs when the got and lost focus (and other states).